# EWS - notification on new mail

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am looking into using the EWS managed API to get notifications on new mails from an Exchange server. I need this notification for all incoming mails on the server, not just for a single user. From what I can see there is no easy way to do this using the EWS since I am bound to sign in using a specific email account. Does any of you know if there is a way to solve this, either using EWS or setting up the accounts i Exchange in a specific way?

I will have > 50k email accounts in my Exchange server that I need to monitor so setting up listners for each and every one using EWS is not an option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Are Transport Agents an option for you ? with a Transport Agent you intercept messages while they are in the Transport Pipeline and before they hit the Mailbox https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125012(v=exchg.141).aspx . EWS works in the context of Mailbox Folders so subscriptions would always need to be per mailbox. If you journal Mail Traffic to a journal mailbox you could then access a copy of all new messages that way and then you only need to work with one mailbox.

Cheers
Glen